# Adding a user control from solution explorer to a winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having trouble drag-dropping user controls into the design view on a winform.  I am able to go through the toolbox, create a new tab, and choose items drag drop my control.

I am unable to go in through the design view and drag the control onto the design view.  Is design view from solution explorer drag-drop supported?  Going through the toolbox is a lot of steps which makes it hard to test.  Is the toolbox the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ToolBox is the only option to drag-drop (custom) controls onto a winform. When you create a seperate assembly for custom controls and reference it in the project where you need the controls VS2010 should automatically add your custom controls (from the referenced project) to the ToolBox. Although the ToolBox behaves "weird" sometimes for unknown reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that it is supported.

The control needs to be compiled before it can be used in the form.  So dragging from the solution explorer would not be possible.